# ActionLoader function on parent route submitted from child route redirects back to parent route

Tags: remix.run

So I am struggling with something that I am sure has an elegant solution that I am missing. I have a nested route system where the parent `/data/streams` (green) has a list of items that have action forms on them and where the action loader is located. However, these can be submitted from a child route `/data/streams/$streamId` (purple). All works fine except if the user is on a child route they are redirected back to the parent. I can kind of solve this with `redirect` and embedding the current location in the small pause form, but then I can't use `useActionData` for displaying error notifications when a call fails.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remix treats `<Form>` submissions as navigations (standard browser feature). That is why your child route POST is navigating to the parent route (since that's where you're posting to).

Remix also supports form submissions that are **not** navigations (standard fetch). To do this, use `<fetcher.Form>`. NOTE: data returned from the action is available on `fetcher.data`. Also check `fetcher.state` and `fetcher.submission` to handle optimistic UI.

```js
const fetcher = useFetcher()
return <fetcher.Form method="post" action="/data/streams">
```

https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/api/remix#usefetcher

Comment: How is this an improvement in web development? It's complicating simple things. So if you have a parent component with multiple forms on it, you need multiple action handlers at the parent level to handle all of its children? Like what am i missing here ...

Comment: I think it would be best to ask a new question and give an example of what you're trying to do.